# How can I make a range selection on element after inline bold tags?

Tags: javascript, html, range

I have tried everything I can think of, but for the life of me I can't programmatically select any text after the bold tag. I have tried setStart on all of the 3 nodes in the childNodes array, but it still won't work.

Can someone explain what I need to do to get it to work?

```
<div class = "tr" id = "data">
     This text is <b>bold</b> as well it should be.
</div>

<button onclick="makeSelection(1,10);">Selection before bold</button>
<button onclick="makeSelection(35,38);">Selection after bold</button>
```

And then the JS:

```
function makeSelection(start, end) {
var parent = document.getElementById('data');

var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(parent.childNodes[0], start);
        range.setEnd(parent.childNodes[0], end);

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range); 
 }
```

***[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ztj5/4/)***

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you wanted but you could simply pass the childNode index as part of the function call?

```
<div class = "tr" id = "data">
 This text is <b>bold</b> as well it should be.
</div>

<button onclick="makeSelection(1,18, 0);">Selection before bold</button>
<button onclick="makeSelection(1,23, 2);">Selection after bold</button>
```

And then simply change the script to use this variable:

```
function makeSelection(start, end, child) {
var parent = document.getElementById('data');

var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(parent.childNodes[child], start);
    range.setEnd(parent.childNodes[child], end);

    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range); 
}
```

As your current code stands it would never be able to reach the 35th - 38th position as you are still in the first child node. Calling this will search the node and receive an out of bounds exception as the first node is only 19 chars long.